# How can I run jfree chart as applet?

Tags: java, applet, jfreechart

I dont have much understanding in java but want the following code to run as applet. Request sincere help on this.

Can anyone help me running this code as applet? This is Jfree chart and i want to run it as an applet. Suggestion please.

```
package org.jfree.chart.demo;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.StandardChartTheme;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.time.Month;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RectangleInsets;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

/**
 * An example of a time series chart.  For the most part, default settings are
 * used, except that the renderer is modified to show filled shapes (as well as
 * lines) at each data point.
 */
public class TimeSeriesChartDemo1 extends ApplicationFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    {
        // set a theme using the new shadow generator feature available in
        // 1.0.14 - for backwards compatibility it is not enabled by default
        ChartFactory.setChartTheme(new StandardChartTheme("JFree/Shadow",
                true));
    }

    /**
     * A demonstration application showing how to create a simple time series
     * chart.  This example uses monthly data.
     *
     * @param title  the frame title.
     */
    public TimeSeriesChartDemo1(String title) {
        super(title);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = (ChartPanel) createDemoPanel();
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a chart.
     *
     * @param dataset  a dataset.
     *
     * @return A chart.
     */
    private static JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) {

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
            "Legal & General Unit Trust Prices",  // title
            "Date",             // x-axis label
            "Price Per Unit",   // y-axis label
            dataset,            // data
            true,               // create legend?
            true,               // generate tooltips?
            false               // generate URLs?
        );

        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0));
        plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
        plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);

        XYItemRenderer r = plot.getRenderer();
        if (r instanceof XYLineAndShapeRenderer) {
            XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) r;
            renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
            renderer.setBaseShapesFilled(true);
            renderer.setDrawSeriesLineAsPath(true);
        }

        DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
        axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy"));

        return chart;

    }

    /**
     * Creates a dataset, consisting of two series of monthly data.
     *
     * @return The dataset.
     */
    private static XYDataset createDataset() {

        TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("L&G European Index Trust");
        s1.add(new Month(2, 2001), 181.8);
        s1.add(new Month(3, 2001), 167.3);
        s1.add(new Month(4, 2001), 153.8);
        s1.add(new Month(5, 2001), 167.6);
        s1.add(new Month(6, 2001), 158.8);
        s1.add(new Month(7, 2001), 148.3);
        s1.add(new Month(8, 2001), 153.9);
        s1.add(new Month(9, 2001), 142.7);
        s1.add(new Month(10, 2001), 123.2);
        s1.add(new Month(11, 2001), 131.8);
        s1.add(new Month(12, 2001), 139.6);
        s1.add(new Month(1, 2002), 142.9);
        s1.add(new Month(2, 2002), 138.7);
        s1.add(new Month(3, 2002), 137.3);
        s1.add(new Month(4, 2002), 143.9);
        s1.add(new Month(5, 2002), 139.8);
        s1.add(new Month(6, 2002), 137.0);
        s1.add(new Month(7, 2002), 132.8);

        TimeSeries s2 = new TimeSeries("L&G UK Index Trust");
        s2.add(new Month(2, 2001), 129.6);
        s2.add(new Month(3, 2001), 123.2);
        s2.add(new Month(4, 2001), 117.2);
        s2.add(new Month(5, 2001), 124.1);
        s2.add(new Month(6, 2001), 122.6);
        s2.add(new Month(7, 2001), 119.2);
        s2.add(new Month(8, 2001), 116.5);
        s2.add(new Month(9, 2001), 112.7);
        s2.add(new Month(10, 2001), 101.5);
        s2.add(new Month(11, 2001), 106.1);
        s2.add(new Month(12, 2001), 110.3);
        s2.add(new Month(1, 2002), 111.7);
        s2.add(new Month(2, 2002), 111.0);
        s2.add(new Month(3, 2002), 109.6);
        s2.add(new Month(4, 2002), 113.2);
        s2.add(new Month(5, 2002), 111.6);
        s2.add(new Month(6, 2002), 108.8);
        s2.add(new Month(7, 2002), 101.6);

        TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(s1);
        dataset.addSeries(s2);

        return dataset;

    }

    /**
     * Creates a panel for the demo (used by SuperDemo.java).
     *
     * @return A panel.
     */
    public static JPanel createDemoPanel() {
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(createDataset());
        ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        panel.setFillZoomRectangle(true);
        panel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
        return panel;
    }

    /**
     * Starting point for the demonstration application.
     *
     * @param args  ignored.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TimeSeriesChartDemo1 demo = new TimeSeriesChartDemo1(
                "Time Series Chart Demo 1");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Why an applet?  An `ApplicationFrame` can be launched direct from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: @Andrew bcoz I need to launch it from applet only...

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend the Applet class and override the `paint(Graphics g)` method.  the key code is `chart.draw( (Graphics2D) g,getBounds());` to used the draw the chart on the `Graphics g`.

If you are new to Java you may want to take a look at the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/)

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.time.Month;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.RectangleInsets;

public class AppletDemo extends JApplet {

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(createDataset());
        chart.draw( (Graphics2D)g,getBounds()); 
    }

    private static JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) {

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
            "Example Chart",  
            "Date",            
            "Value",   
            dataset,            
            true,               
            true,               
            false              
        );

        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0));
        plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
        plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);

        XYItemRenderer r = plot.getRenderer();
        if (r instanceof XYLineAndShapeRenderer) {
            XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) r;
            renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
            renderer.setBaseShapesFilled(true);
            renderer.setDrawSeriesLineAsPath(true);
        }

        DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
        axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy"));

        return chart;

    }

    private static XYDataset createDataset() {

        TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("Series 1");
        s1.add(new Month(2, 2001), Math.random());
        s1.add(new Month(3, 2001), Math.random());
        s1.add(new Month(4, 2001), Math.random());
        s1.add(new Month(5, 2001), Math.random());


        TimeSeries s2 = new TimeSeries("Series 2");
        s2.add(new Month(2, 2001), Math.random());
        s2.add(new Month(3, 2001), Math.random());
        s2.add(new Month(4, 2001), Math.random());
        s2.add(new Month(5, 2001), Math.random());
        s2.add(new Month(6, 2001), Math.random());


        TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(s1);
        dataset.addSeries(s2);

        return dataset;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.........I am working to change that into applet....will bug to frequently.

Comment: Above code is not running.....applet is not initializing...java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/data/time/RegularTimePeriod
         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0

Comment: Its working OK using JFreeChart 1.0.13, all the JFreeChart code was applied as it from your example - does that compile?

Comment: @user1571213 Are you using an IDE or the command line? Check the JFreeChart [FAQ](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/faq.html#FAQ1) for advice on Classpath

Comment: I am using commandline....ok....i am using 1.0.14 version...thats y its not working.

Comment: @user1571213 In that case I suspect that original example may have had the same error.  The applet part should be OK.  Can I recommend that you switch to using an IDE, [Eclipse]( http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/junor) is a good starting point.

Comment: 1.0.13 is also having the same problem.Does it means freechart applet cannot me run from commandline.Its strange!!!

Comment: As you are getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` error I suspect that you problem is not having JFreeChart on your [Class Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) rather than a problem with JFreeChart.

Comment: i able to compile successfully.....for applet is there any dependency?......I am just calling an applet from html page. My class path is OK....

Comment: C:\Users\20010869\Desktop\java\jfree>
C:\Users\20010869\Desktop\java\jfree>appletviewer jfree.html
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/data/time/RegularTimePeriod
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:795)

Comment: When the advice you have includes 'mix Swing with AWT (needlessly)', please refrain from offering it.  That code uses an AWT based `Applet` rather than the Swing based `JApplet` and includes components that are Swing based (e.g. `ChartPanel`).

Comment: I am able to compile now. i have now one problem now.....I able to compile the .java file and able to generate .class file. Now when i run in applet through .html file it throws error. But If i add ARCHIVE tag as "jcommon-1.0.16.jar, jfreechart-1.0.13.jar, appletdemo.jar"  then it works fine......I dont want to add ARCHIVE tags......Can anyone tell....howz that possible.

Comment: @GrahamA BTW - superlative answer even without the screen shot, but just a quick tip from [how do I create great screen-shots](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) - Press `Alt`+ `Print Screen` to limit the screen capture to only the active window.