# applet open multi windows jfree chart

Tags: java, jfreechart, japplet

I'm using jfreechart to create a ternary chart and run it as applet.
the chart display correctly but when i exten it to an applet class and overwrite the paint function it open 5 different windows for the graph not sure why?

here is the code if you can help me.

```
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        DefaultXYDataset dataset = new DefaultXYDataset();
        dataset.addSeries("Red circles",new double[][]{{0, 1, 0.5,0.1, 0.6, 0.2, 0}, {1, 0, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0}});   
        XYPlot plot = new TriangularXYPlot();
        plot.setDataset(dataset);
        XYItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.RED);
        renderer.setSeriesShape(0, new Ellipse2D.Double(-1, -1, 2, 2)); //point shape
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Triangular Demo", new Font("Tahoma", 2, 18), plot, true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("XY Plot Demo");
        ChartPanel cPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        frame.getContentPane().add(cPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        cPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 540));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        chart.draw( (Graphics2D)g,getBounds()); 
    }
```

i wanted to clear that when i use code here:
[How can I run jfree chart as applet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897303/how-can-i-run-jfree-chart-as-applet)
 i got a correct one window.

but when i add:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("XY Plot Demo");
    ChartPanel cPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    frame.getContentPane().add(cPanel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    cPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 540));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

i got multi windows again. and if i did not use this the output window become very small.